# select default tab after app start

Tags: android, tabs

i have an android app with an tab activity und three tabs.
This will be create in my Overview.class
In my OverviewPageAdapter.class i get the correct class and layout for each tab content.

I have a Settings Activity where the user can select a default tab, for example -> tab2
this i will save into the sharedpref.
Now i would like to realize, that tab 2 will be shown as start tab.
How can i do this, that tab 2 each time will be shown at first , when i see the Overview Activity ?

**Overview.class**

```
 public class Overview extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.overview);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);





        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.Tab1)));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.Tab2)));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.Tab3)));

        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.page_adapter);
        final OverviewPageAdapter adapter = new OverviewPageAdapter (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

/*** SET TAB 2 as START TAB ****/
viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
/********/


        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {


            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }


        });
    }
}
```

**OverviewPageAdapter.class**

```
public class OverviewPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
int mNumOfTabs;

public OverviewPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            OverviewTab1 tab1 = new OverviewTab1();
            return tab1;
        case 1:
            OverviewTab2 tab2 = new OverviewTab();
            return tab2;
        case 2:
            OverviewTab3 tab3 = new OverviewTab3();
            return tab3;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
}
}
```

**OverviewTab1.class**

```
public class OverviewTab1 extends Fragment {

private View FragementView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FragementView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overview_tab1, container, false);
    return FragementView;
}
}
```

**OverviewTab2.class**

```
public class OverviewTab2 extends Fragment {

private View FragementView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FragementView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overview_tab2, container, false);
    return FragementView;
}
}
```

**OverviewTab3.class**

```
public class OverviewTab3 extends Fragment {

private View FragementView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FragementView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overview_tab3, container, false);
    return FragementView;
}
}
```

**overview_tab1.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TAB1"
    android:id="tvNoData"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:alpha="1"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:allowUndo="false" />
```

**overview_tab2.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TAB2"
    android:id="tvNoData"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:alpha="1"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:allowUndo="false" />
```

**overview_tab3.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TAB3"
    android:id="tvNoData"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:alpha="1"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:allowUndo="false" />
```

**overview.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/page_adapter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check `getTabAt // Set INDEX`

```
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(0); // Count Starts From 0
    tab.select();
```

Edited

```
 viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
       if(position == 2){  // if you want the third page, for example
           //Your code here
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
});
```

Comment: i put your code in my overview.class under the line "viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);" and set ...getTabAt(2), but tab 0 will be selected :/

Comment: this works, BUT now i see the next Problem. 

i check at the beginning which tab was selected as default under settings like this:

if (prefs.getString("Tab", "") == "tab3") {viewPager.setCurrentItem(2); }


Now i start my app, tab 3 is selected, but when i touch on tab 1, the content of tab 3 will be shown, too. if i touch back on tab 3 and thang again tab 1, than i get the content of tab 1

Comment: Glad to hear that works . For your second question ,You can use `viewPager.getCurrentItem()`

Comment: where i set getcurrentItem?

Comment: and there i put only viewPager.getCurrentItem() ?

Comment: Yes . At first use `Log.d` like this way , `Log.d("getCurrentItem", String.valueOf(viewPager.getCurrentItem()));`

Comment: mmmh i dont understand at the moment, why should i do this. in the normal case (tab 1 ist default tab) it works all fine. i have only the problem if another tab (tab2 or tab3) is the start tab. i made an video - watch it please :) http://tinyurl.com/jegkwck

Comment: `TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(2); ` and `viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);`

Comment: this doesn't work :/ i will send you my project to your email in a few minutes

Comment: As your wish . #Ghost118

Comment: okay, sry i can't send you this project completely. what can we do now?

Comment: show at my first post, there are all classes and layouts

Comment: what should this tutorial do for me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96889/discussion-between-ghost108-and-intellij-amiya).